# How to handle multiple simultaneous inputs to a FIFO?

Tags: verilog, fifo

My verilog code generates DAC ramp signals (channel, value) for 8 channels. I am adding this functionality to a project that already has a DAC controller/communicator and associated FIFO. I would like to add the data I generate simultaneously for all 8 channels to this existing FIFO. I have easily done this for a single channel, but I am not sure the best way to include all the channels.

The ramps are not very fast, and all the clocks are 50 MHz. So, I have many clock cycles (~150+) to work with. However, data could come from multiple channels in the same clock cycle.

Should I create 8 FIFOs (only big enough for a few instructions), 1 per channel? Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

If I lose an occasional data point, that wouldn't be a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is simple CDC fifo or something else but this can be done in many ways, if You have plenty of time before arrival of next data packet then You can:

- (1) In push domain implement simple round-robin algorithm that will push data from each channel sequentially. You might want to add 3bit side-band signal for channel identification so that pop domain could distribute it further based on actual data origin.
- (2) aggregate all data before push to the FIFO and just make FIFO data port width equal to width of 8x input channels. In the pop domain You can de-aggregate it again (if needed), positioning should be deterministic so this operation would be very straightforward.

If there is need for some sort of more sophisticated data flow management You might be forced to use 8 separate FIFOs.